# Why is this bit (Boolean) field not coming through in my C# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication

Thanks for taking a look at my question. So straight to the problem that is slowly making me crazy.

I'm trying to make the logging module of a system in C# and I'm running into trouble, I have 4 layers that make the system run and the most relevant part of the code is this part which is in the "data" layer:

```
public Boolean ObtenerUsuarioValidar(Entidades.Usuario u1)
    {
        Boolean x = false;
        IDataReader idr = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE usuario='" + u1.usuario + "' AND pwd='" +
            u1.pwd+"';");

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            idr = con.Leer(CommandType.Text, sb.ToString());
            while (idr.Read())
            {
                if((string)idr["usuario"] == u1.usuario & (string)idr["pwd"] == u1.pwd)
                {
                   return x = true;
                   u1.usuario = idr["usuario"].ToString();
                   u1.activo = (Boolean)idr["Activo"];
                }              
            }
            idr.Close();
        }
```

I have a class that handles all my setters and getters called **Entidades.Usuario** and what I'm trying to do is to get the value from *idr["Activo"]* and move it up to my presentation layer where I could get a false or true value. in SQL server 2012 the column *Activo* is of type bit.

Here is what I'm trying to do in my Login.cs file:

First I declare a variable of type Entidades.Usuario:

```
  Entidades.Usuario usuario = new Entidades.Usuario();
```

Then later in the same method I try to verify if the user is "activo" or active but no matter what value the database has, the conditional always gives false:

```
else if (usuario.activo == false)
        {
            String msj = "Usuario no activo, porfavor referirse a un administrador";
            MessageBox.Show(msj);
        }
        else
        {

            //if (usuario.rol_id == 3) {
                Principal vb = new Principal();
                vb.Show();
                ((Form)vb).Controls["label2"].Text = usuario.usuario;
```

Do you have any ideas of what might be going on? thanks

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vlunerable to sql injection attacks! you also should not store plain text passwords in a database!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at these lines:

```
               return x = true;
               u1.usuario = idr["usuario"].ToString();
               u1.activo = (Boolean)idr["Activo"];
```

The first line will assign `true` to `x`, and then exit from the method with `true` as return value.

The next two lines are never executed, and you should also find a warning from the compiler that those lines are unreachable code.

You should not have a `return` statement in that place. Not only does it keep the data from being read from the data reader, it also keeps the code at the end of the method from running.

In addition to closing the data reader you should also close/dispose the database connection. You can use `using` statements for those, which makes sure that they are disposed correctly no matter what happens.